# Maruku tells you: what's wrong with me?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, maruku

I use `jekyll --server` to test my site at localhost.
But there are a few lines of input, like this:

```
 ___________________________________________________________________________
 | Maruku tells you:
 +---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | String finished while reading (break on []) already read: "$ git init"
 | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 +---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 !/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maru/errors_management.rb:49:in `maruku_error'
 !/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/input/parse_span_better.rb:402:in `read_simple'
 !/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/input/parse_span_better.rb:521:in `read_inline_code'
 !/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/input/parse_span_better.rb:89:in `read_span'
 !/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/input/    parse_span_better.rb:46:in    `parse_span_better'
 \___________________________________________________________________________
 ___________________________________________________________________________
 | Maruku tells you:
 +---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Could not find ref_id = "url" for md_link(["url"],"url")
 | Available refs are []
 +---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Not creating a link for ref_id = "url".
```

I don't know where is wrong, which file I should fix?
The site could still work.

Answer (score 10):

The issue is most likely you have this in your code:

```
Blah blah [url] blah blah.
```

If you want to keep square bracket, encode them like this:

```
Blah blah \[url\] blah blah.
```

More here: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash

Answer (score 1):

I came across this, and the cause was the Markdown file had been copied from a GitHub README.md, which contained some [GitHub-Flavoured Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/):

````
```JavaScript
var foo = 'bar';
```
````

This works fine inside a GitHub README.md file, but doesn't work with Maruku in Jekyll, which means that it doesn't work when hosting a site with [GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/categories/20/articles).